# X64 assembly, how to have a function always return the same int

Tags: assembly, 64-bit, mach-o

Assembly beginner here, please be gentle!
I have the following x64 assembly procedure and would like to patch it to always return a 15 (type int).

```
0000000000005f2c         push       rbp
0000000000005f2d         mov        rbp, rsp
0000000000005f30         mov        eax, dword [ds:rdi+0x18c]
0000000000005f36         pop        rbp
0000000000005f37         ret
```

How do I do that? Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the code at `5F30` to `mov eax, 15`. Since that is just 5 bytes and you have 6, add a `NOP` for padding. Machine code bytes `B8 0F 00 00 00 90`.

If you want to patch a file, you will first have to find the proper offset of course.